# Passing expression to Linq to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to get the following method to work:

```
private static IQueryable<TObject> ApplyOrderBy<TObject, TKey>(IQueryable<TObject> query, OrderByDirection orderByDirection,
                                                        Expression<Func<TObject, TKey>> sortExpression, ref bool first)
{
    if (orderByDirection == OrderByDirection.None || sortExpression == null) return;
    if (orderByDirection != OrderByDirection.Ascending && orderByDirection != OrderByDirection.Descending)
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Should never get here! Unknown OrderByDirection enum - '{0}'.", orderByDirection));

    if (first)
    {
        first = false;
        query = orderByDirection == OrderByDirection.Ascending
                    ? query.OrderBy(sortExpression)
                    : query.OrderByDescending(sortExpression);
    }
    else
    {
        query = orderByDirection == OrderByDirection.Ascending
                    ? ((IOrderedQueryable<TObject>)query).ThenBy(sortExpression)
                    : ((IOrderedQueryable<TObject>)query).ThenByDescending(sortExpression);
    }

    return query;
}
```

This method works great if you call it like this:

```
ApplyOrderByToGet(ref query, OrderByDirection.Ascending, x => x.StartDateTime, ref first);
```

The sort expression then has a strongly typed DateTime as the type and LINQ to SQL is happy.  However, if you want to pass an array of these expressions with varying types, you ultimately need a list with "object" as the type.  Problem is that LINQ to SQL does not figure out that the type is not object, but instead is DateTime.  This works with a regular list using LINQ to objects.
Seeing as it’s possible to navigate the expression tree and find out what the type is, would it be possible to cast/convert the expression before calling ApplyOrderBy?

Cast or convert from:

```
Expression<Func<T, object>>
```

to:

```
Expression<Func<T, DateTime>>
```

Comment: Why are you using the `ref` keyword? `IQueryable<TObject>` is already a reference.

Comment: The linq OrderBy returns a new query, it does not modify the query you run it on.

Comment: Missed that. I would return the new query instead of using `ref`. That keyword is only a few steps up from `goto` as far an I'm concerned.

Comment: LOL Yea, that would be consistant with how the other LINQ query methods work. I will make the change. Sadly does not get me closer to an actual solution. So frustrating, should be easy.